# Calling a function in the Form Class from another Class, C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Can someone please let me know by some code how I can call a function located in the Form class from another class?

Some code will be of great help!

thanks

EDIT: This is my current code

```
 public partial class frmMain : Form
 {
    //*******Class Instances*******
    ImageProcessing IP = new ImageProcessing();


    //********************
    public void StatusUpdate(string text)
    {
        tlsStatusLabel.Text = text;
    }//


    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }//
}


class ImageProcessing
{

    private void UpdateStatusLabel(frmMain form, string text)
    {
        form.StatusUpdate(text);
    }//

   private UpdateLabel()
   {
        UpdateStatusLabel(frmMain, "Converting to GreyScale");
   }
}
```

the problem i am having is with frmMain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access form component from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803970/access-form-component-from-another-class)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is to create a reference of the MainForm in your Program.cs file as listed above.

Alternatively you can create a static class to handle calls back to your main form:

```
    public delegate void AddStatusMessageDelegate (string strMessage);

    public static class UpdateStatusBarMessage
        {

        public static Form mainwin;

        public static event AddStatusMessageDelegate OnNewStatusMessage;

        public static void ShowStatusMessage (string strMessage)
            {
            ThreadSafeStatusMessage (strMessage);
            }

        private static void ThreadSafeStatusMessage (string strMessage)
            {
            if (mainwin != null && mainwin.InvokeRequired)  // we are in a different thread to the main window
                mainwin.Invoke (new AddStatusMessageDelegate (ThreadSafeStatusMessage), new object [] { strMessage });  // call self from main thread
            else
                OnNewStatusMessage (strMessage);
            }

        }
```

Put the above into your MainForm.cs file inside the namespace but separate from your MainForm Class.
Next put this event call into your MainForm.cs main class.

```
     void UpdateStatusBarMessage_OnNewStatusMessage (string strMessage)
     {
          m_txtMessage.Caption = strMessage;
     }
```

Then when you initialise the MainForm.cs add this event handle to your form.

```
     UpdateStatusBarMessage.OnNewStatusMessage += UpdateStatusBarMessage_OnNewStatusMessage;
```

In any UserControl or form associated with the form (MDI) that you want to call, just us the following...

```
     UpdateStatusBarMessage.ShowStatusMessage ("Hello World!");
```

Because it is static it can be called from anywhere in your program.

Comment: thanks! i tried your option but i am getting an error in "OnNewStatusMessage(strMessage);" saying that OnNewStatusMessage is not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I just wanted to say TY TY TY TY TY TY TY TY lol. Since I've learned how to write my own controls, and use those, and not clutter up m y main form with code that shoudln't be there, this thread has helped me in soooooooooooooooooo many good ways.  Bravo!

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution! It was very easy to understand and I was able to get this working without a hitch. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do that in easy way:

1- create public class and define public static variable like this:

```
class Globals
{
   public static Form1 form;
}
```

2- in load function at the form write this line:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.form= this;
    }

    public void DoSomthing()
    {
        ............
    }
}
```

3- finally, in your custom class you can call all public functions inside the form:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Func1()
    {
        Globals.form.DoSomthing();
    }
}
```

I hope this code will be useful to you:)

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy. Either pass a reference to an existing form in the call, or create a new instance of your form and then call your method just like any other:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public void DoSomethingElse(MyForm form)
    {
        form.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Or make it a static method so you don't have to create an instance (but it won't be able to modify open form windows).

**UPDATE**

It looks like the ImageProcessing class never gets a reference to the form. I would change your code slightly:

```
class ImageProcessing
{
    private frmMain _form = null;    

    public ImageProcessing(frmMain form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }

    private UpdateStatusLabel(string text)
    {
        _form.StatusUpdate(text);
    }
}
```

And then one small tweek in the Form constructor:

```
ImageProcessing IP = new ImageProcessing(this);
```

Comment: thanks, but how I would call the DoSomethingElse Function? My problem is what to type in the "form"? I am trying to insert the form name but I am getting an error that the form name is a type but used as a variable

Comment: @mouthpiec - If you post some of your existing code, we might be able to give you a better idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Post your code, you must bhe doing something very wrong to get that compiler error.

Comment: thanks Justin ... still not working :(
I am getting an error in ImageProcessing IP = new ImageProcessing(this); saying that "this" is an uknown word. (but this constructor needs to have 1 argument.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new Form instance and then call it using the instance. If it is static then you can just call it by calling Form1.Method().

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Method();
```

I would suggest you move this common method to some other class.

If it is common method to be used in the UI then create a base Form class and derive all your forms with this base form class. Now move this common method to the base form. You can then use the method from any of the Form derived from it.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is not related to the UI, an from your example i understand that it's not, you can create another class that will contain this method and then use it in your Form class and in any other places where you want to use it.