# Accessing MainForm from another class file

Tags: c#, class

I have this MainForm class:

```
namespace homework_001{

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {InitializeComponent();}

    public string Change
    {
        get{ return label.Text;}
        set{ label.Text = value;}
    }

     void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test a = new Test();
        a.changer();


    }
}}
```

And I have this class:

```
namespace homework_001{

public class Test
{       
    private MainForm form = new MainForm ();
    public void changer(){
    form.Change = "qqqqq!";
    }
}}
```

Desired workflow is to change the label/text on button press.
It compiles, but nothing happens after I press the button.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Because you created new `MainForm`, what you need is the very same `MainForm` where you clicked the button. So pass the instance to `Test` class through constructor parameter, and use the same.

Comment: Though this is a homework, i really don't see any benefit it provides rising developers. This doesn't even comply with Single Responsibility concept

Comment: @RonaldEstacion no, this namespace just left from another project, I just changed the form for testing purposes instead of creating a new solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access form component from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803970/access-form-component-from-another-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that the form you are showing is not the same as the one inside the class `Test`.

To make things work you should pass the form to the class `Test` in this way:

```
public class Test
{       
    private MainForm form;
    public Test(MainForm f)
    {
        this.form=f;
    }
    public void changer(){
    form.Change = "qqqqq!";
    }
}}
```

and in your main form you do this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {InitializeComponent();}

    public string Change
    {
        get{ return label.Text;}
        set{ label.Text = value;}
    }

     void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test a = new Test(this);
        a.changer();


    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating another `MainForm` object, different from the one that's actually displayed on the screen. To work on the same object you need to pass it to the `Test` class, like this:

```
Test a = new Test(this);   // "this" is the MainForm object you want to work with
a.changer();
```

This will [give `Test` class a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) to your `MainForm` object.

Now, you need to create a [*constructor*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) in `Test` with one argument, and store the received reference to your form object in `Test`'s `private MainForm form` field. You shouldn't have any trouble doing that.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it! Really helpful and quick answer, I appreciate this! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

done create a new object of the main form.. Instead. make the string `Change public and static`
and change it from test class like `Mainform.Change="some text";`

Answer (score -1):

change you code below:

```
 void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test a = new Test();
        a.changer(ref this);


    }
```

you pass the form object to function by refrence and changed that

```
 public class Test
    {       
       public void changer(ref MainForm form){
        form.Change = "qqqqq!";
        }
    }
```

refer this link [Passing Reference-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx)